# In a Windows service, do global static variables get cleared on "restart"?

Tags: .net, windows-services

I have a .NET-based Windows service.  If I "restart" that service, do global static variables get reinitialized?  Is a stop/start sequence different?

Comment: Is your actual question _"Does the service process exit when I restart a Windows Service?"_? Because the answer to _"What is the lifetime of a static variable?"_ is _"The same as the AppDomain containing it"_, and the answer to _"When is an AppDomain unloaded?"_ is _"When the process exits"_.

Comment: Also, Restart is just a services.msc UI feature, it performs a ControlService(stop) followed by a StartService, so yes, the process exits when you restart a service.

Comment: @CodeCaster To clarify little bit "When is an AppDomain unloaded?" If it is a Default Domain it is "When the process exits". Otherwise either when a call to `AppDomain.Unload` is made or when process exit.

Comment: @Sriram of course, but I am asking the question pretending to be OP, assuming OP is using one AppDomain, namely the default AppDomain of his service executable. I am not making claims for all executables using more than one AppDomain.